# Call javascript method inside the sweetalert function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use sweetalert to alert the user to download a file. This is my sweetlaert code. The sweetalert is working fine, but when the user press "OK" I want chrome to show the dialogue box to download file.

```
swal({
   title: 'Confirm',
   text: 'Are you sure you would like to Export ' +totalRecords+" Records",
   type: 'warning',
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonText: 'Yes, sir',
   cancelButtonText: 'Not at all',
     closeOnConfirm: false,
     closeOnCancel: false
    },function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Exported", "Export complete", "success");
            exportTableToCSV.apply(button, [$('#inside_table>table'), outputFile]);
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Export cancelled", "error");
    }
});
```

exportToCSV function is working fine if I take it out of the if statement and call the method outside. This is the exportToCSV function ->

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)')
            ,$rows = $table.find('tr:has(td:has(input:checked))')
            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            ,tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11) // vertical tab character
            ,tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0) // null character
            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            ,colDelim = '","'
            ,rowDelim = '"\r\n"';
            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            var csv = '"';

            csv += formatRows($headers.map(grabRow));
            csv += rowDelim;
            csv += formatRows($rows.map(grabRow)) + '"';
            // Data URI
            var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename
                    ,'href': csvData
                    //,'target' : '_blank' //if you want it to open in a new window
    });
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Helper Functions
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Format the output so it has the appropriate delimiters
    function formatRows(rows){
            return rows.get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                    .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                    .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim);
    }
    // Grab and format a row from the table
    function grabRow(i,row){

            var $row = $(row);
            //for some reason $cols = $row.find('td') || $row.find('th') won't work...
            var $cols = $row.find('td:not(:first-child)');
            if(!$cols.length) $cols = $row.find('th:not(:first-child)');
            return $cols.map(grabCol)
                                    .get().join(tmpColDelim);
    }
    // Grab and format a column from the table
    function grabCol(j,col){
            var $col = $(col),
                    $text = $col.text();
            return $text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put a debugger; statement inside that if and have a look at the variables. I would assume you don't have a reference to that function inside there. A description of the error in the console would be helpful...

Comment: What error message is being displayed in the console?

Comment: when I add console.log(csv) in my exportTableToCSV method, it displays the table information correctly. But the dialogue box to download the file is not coming up.